# Do we need a "How does this site work?" Meta/FAQ overview?

Tags: discussion, meta

Our community appears - from my rough unscientific observations - to be growing.  This is great!  As we grow, I wonder if we'll want to have a single place on Meta to refer new users that covers not only FAQ questions but some of our other settled discussions from beta of what is on and off topic, etc.  The Programmers.SE site has something [similar](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/516/how-does-programmers-site-work), which they got from AskUbuntu.  I think this would also be helpful for us, but am as usual open to disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of this is taken care of by the new(ish) [privileges wiki](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Unless there's something in particular that you think is missing, I think that's where we should be directing people to.  It's pretty discoverable - just click on your reputation score - and I think the team is working on putting a link into the official FAQ at some point (they're aware of the request).

Comment: I was more thinking a place that aggregates on and off topic discussions as well as gives a general overview of what *Seasoned Advice* is about - improving people's culinary skills, not giving them recipes, for example.

Comment: @justkt: I see what you mean, although I've really personally never been a fan of the monolithic FAQ.  They tried that on MSO and eventually had to split it up (and eventually *that* became the privileges wiki).  I'm all in favour of having canonical Q&A on meta that we can link to when somebody asks "Why was my question/answer closed/downvoted/flagged/whatever?"  But as far as my own experience goes, people won't read any of it unless it's immediately relevant to them.  Thus an "index" or "aggregation" doesn't serve much purpose; it makes us all feel good but doesn't really help people.

Comment: Anyway, that's just my opinion.  Now if you want to have this index, so *we* can quickly look *specific* things up to refer *other* users to, then that's another story entirely.  It would be written quite differently from a FAQ though, from a different perspective and to a different audience.

Comment: FAQ is so readily recognizable, even if it's just links to elsewhere, that it sounds nice to me the noob